# Drop Down Menu does not stay centered when browser resize

Tags: html, css, resize

The problem I am having is the formatting of the CSS once the windows resize to smaller. I have been having a lot of trouble, and think that the problem lies in my initial code; I just am not sure where.

I am pretty new to coding and hoping to learn.

[image: Correct Format, large screen]

[image: Resize browser smaller, drop down goes off center]

```css
.nav-main {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 height: 65px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
.nav-main ul {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 font-size: 22px;
 line-height: 100%;
 font-family: 'Futura W01 Bold', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
}
.nav-top {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 66px 0 50px;
 float: none;
 display: inline-block;
 list-style: none;
}
.nav-top:first-child {
 padding-left: 0;
}
.nav-top:last-child {
 background-image: none;
 padding-right: 0;
}
.nav-top:last-child:after {
 content: none;
}
.nav-top > a {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 color: #6f6f6f;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.nav-top a:hover,
.nav-top.active > a {
 color: #454545;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #00e9d9;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-top ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -8.75px;
  width: 105%;
  top: calc(100% - 1px);
  border-bottom-left-radius: .3em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: .3em;

}
.nav-top:hover ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 1px);
  left: -8.75px;
  width: 105%;
}
.nav-top li {
  float: center; 
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: inherit;
}
.nav-top li:last-child {
 padding-bottom: 16px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: .3em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: .3em;
}
.nav-top li > a {
 position: relative;
 display: inline;
 margin: 0;
 color: #6f6f6f;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding-top: 20px;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;

}
.nav-top:after {
 
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: -17px;
    width: 22px;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 100%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
}

@media only screen and (max-width:960px) {
 .nav-main ul {
  font-size: 18px;
 }
 .nav-top ul {
  font-size: 15px;
 }
 .nav-main li {
  padding: 0 46px 0 30px; /* 0 66 0 50 */
 }
 .nav-top li {
  padding-top: 11px;
  text-align: center;/* top 16 bottom 10*/
  float: center;
 }
```

```html
<nav class="nav-main" role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-top"><a href="#welcome">Welcome</a></li>
    <li class="nav-top"><a href="#about">About</a>
      <ul class="drop-down">
        <li class="nav-drop"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li class="nav-drop"><a href="#client">Clients</a></li>
        <li class="nav-drop"><a href="#press">Press</a></li>
        <li class="nav-drop"><a href="#leadership">Leadership</a></li>
        <li class="nav-drop"><a href="#twitter">Follow Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-top"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>     
  <span class="nav-arrow"></span>
</nav>
```

JSFIDDLE[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ywu070y3/)

Comment: use media queries or % for width.

Comment: How can I use % width with the drop down choices? When I've used width it's affected the position of the drop down menu below 'about'

Comment: Your code seems good, even for small screen the drop-down menu is in center.

Comment: what you wnat to achieve? a dropdown menus?

Comment: @aavrug the problem lies in the menu options- I haven't been able to center them. I'm trying to get it to look the same just smaller font from the larger browser size

Comment: @Ron.Basco trying to achieve the choices of the drop down menu centered under about similar to how they are on the larger screen. Once I resize, leadership goes awry almost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.nav-main li` on `@media only screen and (max-width:960px)` is affecting it.

You could either use the `:not` selector `.nav-main li:not(.nav-drop)` or overwrite the `.nav-drop` with `padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0`.

Don't forget to revise it in case you use other media queries.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwfuL3oe)